# PhoneGap: Adding to Blackberry "Send To" Context Menu

Tags: blackberry, mobile, cordova

Is it possible, using PhoneGap, to add a context menu item for when you are browsing photos on a Blackberry and bring up the "Send to" context menu? How can this be done?

Comment: Which RIM OS version are you targeting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this Blackberry Knowledge Base article:
[How To - Add a custom menu item to an existing BlackBerry application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800367/How_To_-_Add_a_custom_menu_item_to_an_existing_BlackBerry_application.html?nodeid=800633&vernum=0)

 I think that it contains the answer of your question.